# gedit on Mac OS X High Sierra via Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, gedit

I just installed **gedit** on Mac OS X 10.13.3 (High Sierra) with Homebrew:

```
brew install gedit
```

The installation was ok but launching it with Terminal I get the error "*(gedit:25359): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 19:20:21.366: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/BPT trap: 5*"
However it runs well launching with:

```
sudo gedit
```

Any help to find where is the error?
I should deinstall Fink and Mac Ports: could it be there the problem?
Thank you
Salvo

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: I could try, but brew doctor has too many warnings, no one error, however.

Comment: however now it works in another computer without Fink and Mac Port, so I'm deinstalling them and trying again in mine...

Comment: Try to solve all warnings given by `brew doctor`, your problem comes from one of those.

Comment: ok, thanks! The problem was gone deinstalling Fink and Mac Ports